# Groovy JavaDocs - Is there a 'since' version label for XmlUtil?

Tags: groovy, gaelyk

I'm trying to find when [XmlUtil](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/xml/XmlUtil.html) was first introduced to Groovy?  Is there a 'since' version X tag somewhere and I'm just not seeing it? In Groovy 2.0.5 I'm getting a missing method exception but not in 2.1.3 for escapeXml().

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static
groovy.xml.XmlUtil.escapeXml() is applicable for argument types: 
(java.lang.String) values: [<request>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XmlUtil has been there for years, however [looking at the blame page on github](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blame/master/subprojects/groovy-xml/src/main/java/groovy/xml/XmlUtil.java#L318), it looks like the `escapeXml` method was added 2013-01-06 as part of the fix for [GROOVY-5775](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-5775) which looking at the issue, shows it went in to Groovy 2.1.0

Comment: Thank you for the research. Very much appreciated.  I am trying to get a Gaelyk 2.0 deployment done and I had some xml I was escaping for presentation on an html page and using that convenience method.  When I switched to the recently available template project now available for Gaelyk 2.0 it has 2.0.5 and starting getting this error after I stopped using my frankenstein version using a Gaelyk 2.0 snapshot and 2.1.x Groovy jars.